# Spirituality of a life from Buddhism

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities, mind

I read a number of books regarding Buddhism. However for me it's a bit hard to identify how to make a life with satisfaction: in other words, I am looking for how to achieve a real happiness of life from myself.

As far as I know, leaving is one way to achieve it.

As a practice, I start to do *Anapanasathi* Meditation, to concentrate my mind. When mind is in concentration, for one thing, it makes freedom feeling of a life.

I need to ask: what is the spirituality of a life?
Please explain it in depth.

Comment: Are you asking "how to achieve lasting happiness according to Buddhism"?

Comment: Yes, great happiness through spirituality of life.

Comment: please edit your question,and make it more clear for everyone

Comment: See also [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25986/254), which will answer this question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might see also [How to explain what Buddhism is?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7258/254)

---

**However for me bit hard to identify how to make a life with satisfaction**

I think that the word *dukkha* is sometimes translated as dissatisfaction.

Is it OK if I say that? You say you've read a number of books regarding Buddhism; so maybe you know about *dukkha* and the Four Noble Truths already, and so I can just refer to them without explaining them?

Anyway, perhaps "a life with satisfaction" might mean "a life without *dukkha*" -- and, well, I think that's the foundation of Buddhist doctrine -- how to live without dukkha.

It involves the cessation of "craving", apparently -- perhaps even cravings for "spirituality", if that makes sense (I don't know what you mean by "spirituality", but maybe you're "craving" it).

An opposite to *dukkha* is *[sukha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha)* (not an exact opposite, but nevertheless). Various forms of Sukha are supposed to be available to lay house-holders -- being ethical, fulfilling all your responsibilities, good friendships, and so on. I might recommend [this book](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25963/254) for more details about that.

Other schools of Buddhism maybe emphasise that it's satisfying to try to help (save) other people.

I think that some people summarise the doctrine[s] as saying that what's "satisfying" is one's own ethical behaviour -- [for example](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26024/254):

> It is the same technique most people unconsciously use to maintain their ego: finding reasons to congratulate oneself, and reinvesting the joy that comes from that into further effort in the same direction. The only difference here is that Buddhists use it consistently with Ethics ...

If I behave well (e.g. generously) then I might remember that good behaviour with some satisfaction (or I might, at least, have "no remorse"). And, to be a bit pedantic, it might be about having good *intention*, rather than only behaviour ... behaviour tends to follow after, follow from, intention.

---

As an addendum, when you talk about "life" and "spirituality", perhaps you're talking about what's translated from the suttas as "holy life" -- perhaps that's [brahmacariya](https://www.buddha-vacana.org/gloss.html#brahmacariya) -- and features in suttas like [this one](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.002.than.html) -- or in [this formula](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/formulae/asavak.html).

However that may give the impression that Buddhism is only for monks, which isn't the whole truth.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one lasting happiness according to Buddhism and that is the ***Nibbana***. To achieve that you need to follow the [noble eightfold path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path).

That means developing virtue (Sila), concentration (Samadhi) and wisdom (Panna).